# How can I find if an element has an h1 element inside it?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#content')
```

What I would like is to check if this has an h1 element inside of it. If it has then I would like to do the following:

```
$('#content').buildTableOfContent();
```

Is there a way I could do this check using jQuery?

Comment: @loler: No, it won't. It will return a jQuery object, which may or may not have any matching elements in it. So `if($('#content').find('h1'))` is **always** truthy (will always enter the `if` block).

Comment: @loler: *(Oh for cryin' out loud...)* No, it doesn't: http://jsbin.com/ememaz With a library like Prototype it would (or the DOM), because Prototype and the DOM return `null` when you ask for a single thing and they can't find it. But jQuery is set-based, `find` always returns an object, which may have zero matches in it.

Comment: @loler: No worries! We should clean up these comments. I'll check back in a few hours and if yours are gone, I'll remove mine as well. :-) Best,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
if ($("#content h1").length > 0) {
    $("#content").buildTableOfContent();
}
```

Comment: @ Gemma: Or if you already have `c = $("#content");` for some reason, `c.find("h1").length > 0`. And instead of `.length > 0`, you can just do `[0]`, e.g.: `if ($("#content h1")[0]) { /* Yes it has it */ }`

Comment: Note that `$('#content h1')` will return all child h1, grandchild h1 and so forth. `$('#content').children('h1')` will limit itself to direct descendants of `#content` only.

Comment: Is there an actual need to perform the comparison `> 0`, I was under the impression that `$('#content h1').length` would evaluate to `false` if it returned `0`, and `true` if `> 0`?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yes, it will. Or (as I say above) you can use the shorter-but-slightly-more-awkward-to-type `[0]` instead of `.length`.

Comment: I'm afraid the other answer is better this time.

Comment: @gdoron Maybe yes, maybe no. Check out the sources. I doubt which is faster.

Comment: The difference is very small and you care about performance so much, you should cache the `#content`

Comment: @gdoron That just shows the conception. IMO, both solutions are possible and easy readable.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done in just one line thank to rich jQuery API:

```
$('#content:has(h1)').buildTableOfContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not fixated on jQuery, this is just

```
if (document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("H1")[0]) {
    ...build TOC...
}
```